# 2010 Sebring maintains speed for about 5 seconds after depressing accelerator pedal

Tags: troubleshooting, chrysler

My car maintains speed for 4 or 5 seconds when releasing gas pedal, then the speed starts dropping slowly. When I’m getting close to a stop light, my car wants to keep going same speed, so I need to start braking harder. There is no sign of a problem. I don’t get any check engine light.

I have cleaned the throttle body thinking that could be the problem. I have to mention that I do hear a clicking noise when I start driving away. This is somewhere around the front axle, but not sure. I did have the clicking noise problem first, now the speed. I don’t know if that is related.

Answer (score 1):

The clicking might be a CV joint or wheel bearing and most likely not related to the throttle issue. First look at the floormats or anything that might be against the gas pedal. Checking a couple of forums I found some items about throttle cable fraying. I would diconnect the cable and cycle the throttle body, see if the spring returns it to the closed position. I would look for fraying, pay particular attention where the cable enters and exits the cable housing. Reattach the cable and have an assisitant cycle the throttle. Watch if the cable returns quickly. You may also have a faulty throttle position sensor. While searching I also found several sites selling throttle cable brackets which may indicate they can be problematic.

Comment: mikes my car has a electronic throttle body and no cable. I forgot to mention that I bought a use throttle body to see if that was the problem but same thing. do you have other suggestions. thanks

Comment: The part you replaced includes the electronically-actuated throttle? If there's anything you didn't replace that's mechanically related to the throttle opening/closing, I would properly clean it. For external stuff, just soap or degreaser followed by a little lubrication. For anything internal, Seafoam or similar. I've found Seafoam does wonders for problems with sticking IAC valves, and while not the same, your issue sounds similar.